# Is it possible for an image not to move to the cursor when the cursor is a certain distance away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code, and in the code, the image will only break away from the cursor if it hits the edge of the div it is contained in. When it enters, the cursor has to be a certain distance from the image for the image to follow the cursor again. So, what I want to do is if the cursor breaks away from anywhere on the page, whether it is in the div or not, the image will stay apart from the cursor until the image is found by the cursor. Is this possible?

```js
  var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
    var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
    if(difLeft < 10 && difLeft > -10 && difTop < 10 && difTop > -10 ){
      startMove = true;
      $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
    }
    if(startMove){
     $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
    else{
     $('html').addClass('showCursor');
    }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function(){
    startMove = false;
})
```

```css
    
        html {cursor: none;}
    html.showCursor{cursor: default;}
    #image{
    position:absolute;
    width:25px;
    height:auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    <img id="image" src="http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/mac-osx-arrow-cursor.png"/>
```

Editable code: https://jsfiddle.net/3x7cgLdr/23/

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks away"?

Comment: I mean the image stops following the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, it's still a bit unclear for me. When do you want the image to stop following the cursor?

Comment: I want the image to stop following the cursor when the cursor gets a certain distance away from the image. As the code demonstrates above, the image will stop following if the image gets to the edge of the page. If I right click, and then escape that, the image goes to the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, my internet connection stopped working for a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I added an `else if` clause that checks if the mouse is gone too far (at least `DIFF_UNSNAP` amount) from the image. This sets the `startMove` to false:

```
var startMove;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  var DIFF_SNAP = 10;
  var DIFF_UNSNAP = 100;
  var difLeft = $('#image').offset().left - e.pageX;
  var difTop = $('#image').offset().top - e.pageY;
  if (!startMove && Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_SNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_SNAP) {
    startMove = true;
    $('html').removeClass('showCursor');
  } else if (startMove && !(Math.abs(difLeft) < DIFF_UNSNAP && Math.abs(difTop) < DIFF_UNSNAP)) {
    startMove = false;
  }
  if (startMove) {
    $("#image").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  } else {
    $('html').addClass('showCursor');
  }
});

$(document).mouseleave(function() {
  startMove = false;
})
```